# Gremlin get first vertex of each loop

Tags: java, gremlin

I'm looping through a graph like this:

[image]

breadth first in Gremlin like this

```
pipe.start(unProcessed)
                .as("x")
                .bothE()
                .as("existingEdge")
                .bothV()
                .hasNot("processed",true)
                .loop("x", new PipeFunction<LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean compute(LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex> loopBundle) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }, new PipeFunction<LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean compute(LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex> loopBundle) {
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .as("newVertex")
                .select(Arrays.asList("x","newVertex"));
```

What I want is the vertex from the start of *this iteration* of the loop, along with the next one. So The results **I want to see** are

1. A,B
2. B,C
3. B,D
4. B,E
5. C,F
6. D,F

However, **what I get is**:

1. A,B
2. A,C
3. A,D
4. A,E
5. A,F
6. A,F

It looks like "x" in the pipeline is always the very first vertex in the pipeline, not the first vertex in that iteration of the loop, which is what I want.

It seems like this should be easy and I'm missing something simple, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's needed is a _() or "IdentityPipe"

```
.as("x")
._()                            
.as("firstVertex")
```

That's what worked for me.